# C# - How to keep chart y-axis gridlines constant?

Tags: c#, charts, grid, gridlines

How to make it so that the number of gridlines on the Y-Axis stays constant, and the values/labels look cleaner and not jagged?

Here's a video recording I did of the chart: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i--1nJ0VhG0

Comment: Set a fixed minimum and maximum for the y-axis so it won't 'optimize'. also set a fixed format for the labels so they keep a constant width.

Comment: @TaW Fixed the label staggering issue, but what do you mean by setting minimum and maximum? my data is random, and i don't want to be truncating information. basically i want the grids to 'glide' smoothly, and not add and remove grid lines. if that makes sense? thanks :)

Comment: Well, the default is Auto and it will optimized the display. charts are not really meant for animations; you can do this: keep a gliding value fot the minimum/maxim values, ie increase the AxisY.Maximum as needed but never bring it down; same for minimum. of course that might lead to too large a range, but you can't have it both way. Or you enforce a constant Interval..